# On premise Workgroup Application to Azure

Tags: azure, myob

I have a bunch of users in Azure AD tenant. There is no on premise server or AD.

I have discovered one of the PC hosts a line of business application (accounting software MYOB) that I would like to migrate to the cloud (Azure).

What is the easiest way to do this?

I had a look at this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/tutorial-configure-networking) - is this the way?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to migrate business application [Onprem] to Azure cloud via "**Azure Migration - Foundation for your Azure Infrastructure**"
as part of setps we need to configure below

1. Create an Azure Infrastructure foundation for VM
2. Create a Virtual Machine in Azure and configure for application
3. Import the Website to the Azure Virtual machine.
4. Configure NSGs.

I have found one reference tutorial with step by step process from [whizlabs](https://www.whizlabs.com/blog/how-to-migrate-your-on-prem-web-app-to-azure-cloud/).

Answer (score 0):

The way I did it in the end, which was simple and secure was to create a Azure Virtual Desktop (Windows 10) AVD.

I then published this AVD to the users that needed it and set it to shutdown each night at 6PM to keep costs down.

Installed the application to a extra disk mounted in the AVD.